# My F# program is trying to connect to the network and I have no network code

Tags: f#

Basically I have been writing a small and horribly inefficient interpreter for a language of my own design for fun. Writing it in F#. The odd part is that when give it some lengthy code to interpret, like my version of a loop, like `"loop true do 0"` (which would translate into an infinate loop), it tries to connect to the network. I know because my firewall notices it and asks me what to do. This is not intentional, I have not a single line of network code in my program. I even changed to loop code in the interpreter as an experiment to just an eternal F# while loop, so it would just loop on forever and not do any interpreter stuff, but it had no effect.

When I say networking related stuff I am talking about connecting to one of these two addresses:
`224.0.0.252`
and
`239.255.255.250`

After googling this I found that `224.0.0.252` has something to do with LLMNR (Link Local Multicast Name Resolution) and `239.255.255.250` has something to do with SSDP (Simple Service Discovery Protocol) but I dont know what that means.

Does anyone have an idea of why my program is doing this?

EDIT:

The loop code looks like this atm (on purpose, to check if it was my code that did it or not):

```
and loopExec scope state cond body =
    while true do ()
    GNil
```

It tries to connect somewhere in the while loop. Before I had this:

```
and loopExec scope state cond body =
    let myig _ = ()
    while (exec scope state cond) <> GBool(false) do
        myig <| exec (pushScope scope) state body
    GNil
```

Where scope is the current scope, state is the current state, cond is the condition and body what should be evaluated as long as cond is true. myig was basically me running out of ideas of what the problem could be, so I made my own ignore function. exec executes the code in cond or body.

Its not the best code, I am aware of that.

EDIT 2:

I just inserted an eternal loop at the entrypoint of the entire program and it still did it... tested both in debug and release mode.

```
// Entrypoint of the program
[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    while true do ()
    // Display the greeting message thing
    displayHelp()
    // Prompt the user for code
    Console.Write("> ");
    let mutable inp = readCode()
    let mutable runCode = true
    let state = new Interpreter.State()
    while inp.Trim() <> "#exit" do
        if not (isValidLine inp) then
            if runCode then
                execCode state inp
            else
                printfn "Result: %A\n" (parseString inp)
        elif inp = "#help" then
            displayHelp()
            printfn ""
        elif inp = "#ast" then
            runCode <- false
        elif inp = "#run" then
            runCode <- true
        elif inp = "#names" then
            showNames state
        Console.Write("> ")
        inp <- readCode()
    // Ask the user to press enter before exiting
    printfn "[PRESS ENTER TO EXIST]"
    Console.Read() |> ignore
    Environment.ExitCode
```

Comment: How about you show us a bit of code.

Comment: The interpreter itself is 276 lines atm. I wouldnt know which part to show. But I guess I can include the loop code. Wait while I edit it in.

Comment: What OS/platform and development environment are you using? Are you running the code in F# Interactive, or compiling it and running it? If compiling, are you running in Debug mode?

Comment: Windows. Running it in debug, but have tried in release and it made no difference. Maybe I should check debug again.

Comment: If I set it to release mode in Visual Studio, build it and run the executable directly from the release folder, I should be running the one compiled in release mode right? If so then its not the debug mode thats the problem, because I just tried and it still tried to connect to the network :(.

Comment: Yes, that's correct (about release mode). Also, after some "Bing-ing" it looks like those two IPs (and protocols) are used together to implement [IGMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Group_Management_Protocol). Based on the code you've shown so far though, I don't know what would be triggering any multicasts though...

Comment: It's nearly impossible to say what might be going on without seeing all of your code. F#, as far as I know, doesn't try to connect to the network until and unless your code directs it to do so.

Comment: I am not sure the code in the interpreter matters. I just shuffled an endless loop into the function that starts it and it still tried to connect to the internet, even if it didnt even do anything. Keep in mind that I inserted this loop before even the parsing stage, so... I dont understand this at all.

Comment: Could it be Visual Studio is trying to download extra information for the debugger or some other purpose? After all if you have no network code in your program then it's probably not your program... For example maybe it's trying to download a .pdb from Microsoft's symbol server and is hitting those IPs as part of the downloading. Just a guess...

Comment: Beware - your computer is now self-aware!

Comment: Are you sure it's not just Visual Studio looking for updates? Are you sure it's even connecting when you run outside VS? Weird..

Comment: I just ran it outside of visual studio and it still did it, so yeah, I am sure. Have included the current entrypoint now. Note the eternal while loop at the very start of the program... I am just puzzled right now.

Comment: @Kerr - why don't you post the complete code that you use to compile an exe as well as your compiler flags.  Without that we are just guessing.

Comment: I am planning to put it up on github this weekend, tbh. So I can link to that when I do.